# SQL Server Select TOP N rows per group where size less than X

Tags: sql-server

I have a table

**id | filename | size | date | order**

And i want to select for each date the n first files that are less than 100Mo (Size)
For example if i have :

Data table:-

[image]

I want to keep only the ID 1, 2 and 11.

I already wrote this but it gives me only the first date group.

```
SELECT
ID,
filename,
size,
date,
ordre
FROM tableName
WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM tableName 
              WHERE ID < 
                   (SELECT TOP 1 ID
                    FROM tableName 
                    WHERE size > 100
                    )
             )
```

Comment: please add some sample table data and the expected result - as well in formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your problem: for every date, I want to get all the rows that are, ordered by ID, prior to the first row of that date that is over 100Mb.

If my understanding is correct, how about something like:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.size, t.date, t.ordre
FROM #tmp t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(ID) AS MinID, [date]
        FROM #tmp 
        WHERE size > 100
        GROUP BY [date]
    ) m ON t.[date] = m.[date]
WHERE t.ID < m.MinID
    OR m.MinID IS NULL -- for when there is no sizes > 100Mb for a date
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: OK tested it on a bigger table it just work very fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
;with x as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by date order by id) rn
    from tablename
    where size < 100
)
select * from x where rn <= @n
```